# How to change title of Activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am using

```
Window w = getWindow();
w.setTitle("My title");
```

to change title of my current Activity but it does not seem to work.

Can anyone guide me on how to change this?

Answer (score 532, accepted):

Try setTitle by itself, like this:

```
setTitle("Hello StackOverflow");
```

Comment: setTitle not working for me, getSupportActionBar() and getActionBar() also nulls i cant set the title in runtime.

Comment: @Ninja_Coding, try calling it from the Activity.

Comment: Or title = "Hello StackOverflow" in Kotlin

Answer (score 264):

Just an FYI, you can optionally do it from the XML.

In the AndroidManifest.xml, you can set it with

```
android:label="My Activity Title"
```

Or

```
android:label="@string/my_activity_label"
```

Example:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/splash_activity_title" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Why would you vote this down? It's good to know you can do it from the XML also.

Comment: This is pretty much the corect way to do it, with references to external strings to enable easy localisation. Should be accepted answer.

Comment: It's not the same as setTitle().  Setting the android:label property of the launcher activity will also change the name of the application on the phone's applications screen. Your application's icon will have "My Activity Title" caption.

Comment: @doran While you are correct, and his example is wrong in a way, he is also right. His issue is adding a label to a splash screen, and you wouldn't do that for a splash screen, rather just label it with the app name. However the label for the whole application is what determines the title given to the launcher if it is set

Comment: This should be the best answer.

Comment: On at least my version of Android Studio, this also changes the name of the app on the home screen, which is not a great idea if you're trying to make the menu title go away with an empty string. :-)

Comment: I had to add android:label="@string/my_activity_label" instead of @strings!

Comment: @BullShark The original question is "How to change title of Activity in Android?". "change" can be interpreted several ways, but based on the OP's use of code I presume he wanted to change the title programmatically. Your example is hard coded. Thus why you might have received down votes (not from me).

Answer (score 29):

If you want it one time & let system handle the rest (not dynamic) then do like this in your manifest file:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name_full" > //This is my custom title name on activity. <- The question is about this one.
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_launcher_name" > //This is my custom Icon title name (launcher name that you see in android apps/homescreen)
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 16):

```
setTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.MyTitle));
```

Comment: @Sujay yes, you can, here you are:

try {
            int labelRes = getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(getComponentName(), 0).labelRes;
            Logger.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "labelRes : " + labelRes);

            if (labelRes > 0 && getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(labelRes);
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException exception) {
            Logger.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "exception caught : " + Log.getStackTraceString(exception));
        }

Answer (score 10):

There's a faster way, just use

```
YourActivity.setTitle("New Title");
```

You can also find it inside the *onCreate()* with this, for example:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.setTitle("My Title");
    }
```

By the way, what you simply cannot do is call setTitle() in a static way without passing any Activity object.

Comment: this doesn't work when pressing the standby button and making the screen active again. The title does not update. Any ideas?

Comment: That's because onCreate() won't be called in your example. You should consider using another event handler instead, such as onResume(). I suggest you to see this link: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    getActivity().setTitle("My Title");
//...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have multiple activities, you can set it like this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NumbersActivity"
        android:label="@string/category_numbers"
        android:theme="@style/category_numbers" />
    <activity
        android:name=".FamilyActivity"
        android:label="@string/category_family"
        android:theme="@style/category_family" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ColorsActivity"
        android:label="@string/category_colors"
        android:theme="@style/category_colors" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PhrasesActivity"
        android:label="@string/category_phrases"
        android:theme="@style/category_phrases" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ExperimentActivity"
        android:label="@string/category_experiment"
        android:theme="@style/category_experiment" />
</application>
```

Comment: i did exactly like this, it did not work. on every activity i am seeing just App Name. Unable to change it. is been now more than half an hour :(

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1.

WIth an Activity:

```
setTitle("Title Text");
```

Inside a fragment:

```
getActivity().setTitle("Title Text");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.Main_Activity);
    this.setTitle("Title name");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set title in Java file, then write in your activity onCreate

```
setTitle("Your Title");
```

if you want to in Manifest then write

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="Your Title" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin, this way:

```
this.title = resources.getText(R.string.fast_learning)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a Toolbar in my Activity and a Base Activity that overrides all Titles. So  I had to use setTitle in onResume() in the Activity like so:

```
@Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.title);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code helped me change the title.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);
    ActivityName.this.setTitle("Your Activity Title");}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside a MainActivity:

```
public class act1 extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act1);

    setTitle("First Activity");

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

setTitle("Whatever apps");
in MainActivity.java is simplier
I would say.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change Title of activity when you change activity by clicking on the Button. Declare the necessary variables in MainActivity:

```
    private static final String TITLE_SIGN = "title_sign";
    ImageButton mAriesButton;
```

Add onClickListener in onCreate() and make new intent for another activity:

```
    mTitleButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.title_button);
    mTitleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
        SignActivity.class);
        String title_act = getText(R.string.simple_text).toString();
        intent.putExtra("title_act", title_act);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        }
    });
```

SecondActivity code in onCreate():

```
    String txtTitle = getIntent().getStringExtra("title_act");
    this.setTitle(txtTitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **onCreateOptionsMenu**, you can also add **setTitle** code in onCreateOptionsMenu.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    setTitle("Neue Aktivität");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setTitle("Welcome Activity");

Comment: Same solution as the accepted answer from 2010