# Trying to set label for Individual Activity

Tags: android

It always displays AndroidAdminApi Label above all the activities. I can change the App Name inside manifest code, But Is there any way to put the Label for individual Activity?

**Android Manifest Code**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Activities.UserManagement.Auth.Login.LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

[image]

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198410/how-to-change-title-of-activity-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198410/how-to-change-title-of-activity-in-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change title of Activity in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198410/how-to-change-title-of-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change like this

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your custom title");
```

Or

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setTitle("Your custom title");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add like this in manifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name=".xyz"
        android:label="XYZ" />


    <activity
        android:name=".abc"
        android:label="ABC" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you change the label for individual activity using `actionBar.setTitle` OR simply `setTitle` in your activity

**1.** Using action bar title

```
getActionBar().setTitle(title);
```

OR

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title); //if you are using appcompat library, also you can try setTitle in your activity directly
```

**2.** Directly specifying label for activity in manifest

```
<activity
    android:name="package.yourActivity"
    android:label="Label" />
```

**3.** Try using setTitle directly in your activity

Answer (score 0):

you should add label option in activity level ( No Activity level )

android:label=“ACTIONBAR_TITLE_TEXT"

Good luck !